# how to show images in grid view?

Tags: android

I have a database which contains list of image path. My problem is I have to show all the images in a grid view.
I have taken list of path from database but i am not able to show all the images in grid layout.
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: what is the exact problem you are facing, please be specific and how somebody comes to know what is not working in your code if there is no code to review?

Comment: I have list of image path, my problem is to show all list of images in grid view

Answer (score 1):

In gridview `setAdapter()` as you normally do for custom `ListView` by extending `BaseAdapter` and passing the arraylist of paths to this adapter class.

Now in `getView()` method of `Adapter` add following lines

```
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
mView.setImageBitmapReset(mBitmap, 0, true);
```

where `mView` is an `ImageView` and path will be fetched from arraaylist that you pass to adapter

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String[] prgmNameList = {"Grid_1", "Grid_1", "Grid_1"};
    int[] prgmImages = new int[] {R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher};

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Gridimageadapter gpa = new Gridimageadapter(MainActivity.this, prgmNameList, prgmImages);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gridView.setAdapter(gpa);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't write only code. Please add an explanation about it.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.